# Match OOXML paragraph with string

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, preg-match

I have OOXML document, i need replace paragraph inside it, to insert table in it place, in my case it simple string `$(test)`

Here i prepare regex https://regex101.com/r/ZTMlEc/2/

I try to make it but without any luck, it matches from first

I need match block that starts with :

```
<w:p w:rsidR="0035180D" w:rsidRDefault="00C7412B" w:rsidP="00945FB5">
```

and ends

```
</w:p>
```

for later replace

problem is there may many other paragraphs in documents, and i try, but cant create regexp to match exactly this one, couse it internal tags may differs.

I need work with this XML like as string, and cant use XML libs for it.

Comment: You could use a parser instead.

Comment: Parser is not option

Comment: Like this: https://regex101.com/r/ZTMlEc/3 ?

Comment: No, i did not know name of the block it may be `${cpu}` or ${header} and MS Word will create different `<w:p></w:p>` with different attributes and tags, but i need to replace `<w:p>${cpu}</w:p>` whith my string, but  `<w:p>` inside tags may contains many other tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem other way.

I just select all `<w:p>` tags and then made `preg_match` on each of them to find first one that have right string. And then just use `str_replace`.

```
   public function insertTable($blockname, $tableText) {

    $pregstr = '/<w:p .*?>([^<]*)<\/w:p>/i';
    preg_match_all(
            $pregstr, $this->tempDocumentMainPart, $matches
    );

    $replacematch = "";

    foreach ($matches[0] as $m) {
        preg_match(
                '/<w:p .*?>.*?<w:t>\$.*?' . $blockname . '.*?<\/w:p>/ims', $m, $amatches
        );
        if (count($amatches) > 0) {
            $replacematch = $amatches[0];
        }
    }

    $this->tempDocumentMainPart = str_replace(
            $replacematch, $tableText, $this->tempDocumentMainPart
    );
}
```